# How can add multiple database for tests in Django tests

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-models

**Question:**

How can I add multiple databases for testing in `Django`?

**When I ran my test suits I got this Error:**

> AssertionError: Database queries to 'mig' are not allowed in this test. Add 'mig' to path_to_test_suit.MigrationServiceTest.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.

Here are my PostgreSQL settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_1_name',
        'USER': 'db_1_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_1_passwd',
        'HOST': 'db_1_host',
        'PORT': 'db_1_port',
    },
    'mig': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': db_2_name,
        'USER': db_2_user,
        'PASSWORD': 'db_2_passwd',
        'HOST': 'db_2_host',
        'PORT': 'db_2_port',
    },
}
```

> I use `Django-nose` for running test suits and use `Django 2.2`

Comment: dis you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I forget the way that I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `database` parameter in your tests.
For example:

```
class TestYourClass(TestCase):
    databases = {'default', 'mig'}

def test_some_method(self):
    call_some_method()
```

For more information please see [Multi-database support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#multi-database-support).

P.S. In earliest Django version than 2.2 please use `multi_db = True`

```
class TestYourClass(TestCase):
    multi_db = True
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to grant DJANGO user the priviledge to write.
Then, to make the tests and preserve your data, you have to make a copy of your schema with test_ as prefix and use the keywork --keepdb.